How to import bundled css files in a "raw" import for a component library?
I'm maintaining a collection of private libraries in a monorepo.
Some libraries contains css (using scss modules), some not.
Because I want to consuming application decide what to do with css of the library, I would to inject, only when it's necessary, an import of the css file. I don't want to inject the CSS in the page or whatever other plugins can do. Just reference the CSS to let the final bundler know there is a css file to handle.
To clarify, I would like to inject import './index.css'; at the top of the bundled js file when such file is present.
The why is well explained in vite-plugin-lib-inject-css, which was working well in the previous architecture of my repo (we are migrating from vite to tsup).
What I tried is to play with banner:
type TsupOptions = Parameters<typeof defineConfig>[0];

function getTsupPackageConfig(): TsupOptions {
    return {
        entry: ["src/index.ts"],
        format: ["cjs", "esm"],
        sourcemap: true,
        clean: true,
        bundle: true,

        esbuildPlugins: [
            sassPlugin(),
        ],
        banner: (ctx) => {
            switch (ctx.format) {
                case "cjs":
                    return { js: `require('./index.css');` };
                case "esm":
                    return { js: `import './index.css';` };
                default:
                    throw new Error(`Unsupported format: ${ctx.format}`);
            }
        },
    };
}

This injects the css file import, but I don't know how to restrict this import to only packages with CSS.
FYI, the actual full code is:
/*
 * tsup.config.ts (in every packages)
 */
import { defineConfig } from "tsup";

import { getTsupPackageConfig } from "../../scripts/getTsupConfig";

export default defineConfig(getTsupPackageConfig());



/*
 * getTsupConfig.ts (in a shared utils folder)
 */
import postcssDts from "@guanghechen/postcss-modules-dts";
import { sassPlugin } from "esbuild-sass-plugin";
import postcss from "postcss";
import postcssModules from "postcss-modules";
import { defineConfig } from "tsup";

type TsupOptions = Parameters<typeof defineConfig>[0];

function getTsupPackageConfig(): TsupOptions {
    return {
        entry: ["src/index.ts"],
        format: ["cjs", "esm"],
        sourcemap: true,
        clean: true,
        bundle: true,
        esbuildPlugins: [
            sassPlugin({
                transform: async (source, resolveDir, filePath) => {
                    const { css } = await postcss([
                        postcssModules({
                            ...postcssDts({
                                semicolon: true,
                            }),
                        }),
                    ]).process(source, {
                        from: filePath,
                    });
                    return css;
                },
            }),
        ],
        loader: {
            ".png": "file",
            ".svg": "file",
        },

        banner: (ctx) => {
            switch (ctx.format) {
                case "cjs":
                    return { js: `require('./index.css');` };
                case "esm":
                    return { js: `import './index.css';` };
                default:
                    throw new Error(`Unsupported format: ${ctx.format}`);
            }
        },
    };
}

export { getTsupPackageConfig };

